# Cannot build / run test properly in travis. Permission denied

Tags: node.js, jestjs, travis-ci

I have a simple node.js code/project. I write some test with jestjs. I run the test on my local machine with the command 'npm run test'. The test is able to pass.

I moved the project onto GitHub and wanted to tinker with Travis CI. But my build on travis ci fails. The error message on travis is shown below.

[image]

Below is the state of my Git repo:

[image]

I never committed the folder 'node_modules' into Git because I read somewhere that this folder should be excluded as Travis would have its 'own environment to run and build the project'.

Below is my .travis.yml :

[image]

Below is my package.json file:

[image]

I tried modifying this file as well. I am still stuck, Should I remove the lines that states the "build" ?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the situation by adding the below:

```
before_script: chmod 0555 ./node_modules/.bin/jest
```

I think this is trying to tell the machine running to allow the use of the jest library. Therefore the jests unit test is able to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding the following to `travis.yml`

`before_script: chmod 0555 ./node_modules/.bin/travis`